# Python 3 fullmatch regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a string that has to have characters A-Z, a-z, and 0-9. If it doesn't, it returns an error.

I have no clue what I'm doing with regex but:

```
if re.fullmatch('[A-Za-z0-9]', nickname):
  print("Yes")
```

Here's what I'm doing, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9]` only matches 1 character, so your string would have to be 1 character long. You need `[A-Za-z0-9]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `+` sign:

```
if re.fullmatch('[A-Za-z0-9]+', nickname):
    print("Yes")
```

Without a `+` sign, it will only match one character.

If you don't need regex you could use the faster way with `isalnum`:

```
if nickname.isalnum():
    print("Yes")
```

Comment: `nickname.isalnum()` is a magnitude faster than the regex!

Comment: @Lego490 it's okay, thought you did :P

Answer (score 1):

Just out of interest did this:

```
# in ipython for the %timeit magick

nickname = 'abcdqajsdkfl83490'
alphanum = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

%timeit nickname.isalnum()
324 ns ± 4.24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

import re
%timeit re.fullmatch("[A-Za-z0-9]+", nickname)
1.77 µs ± 15.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$", nickname)
1.82 µs ± 3.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$", nickname).span()[1] == len(nickname)
2.42 µs ± 27.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit all([x in alphanum for x in nickname])
3.22 µs ± 46.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit sum([x in alphanum for x in nickname]) == len(nickname)
4.02 µs ± 66.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

alnum = set(alphanum)
%timeit alnum.union(set(nickname)) == alnum
## 4.19 µs ± 71.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

import re
%timeit all([re.match("[A-Za-z0-9]", x) for x in nickname])
29.4 µs ± 560 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

the winner is: `.isalnum()` by at least a magnitude of order!